# Inverse Fourier transform of $F(k) = 1/(k^2+a^2), a>0$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform, inverse-function

> I need help finding the Inverse Fourier transform of: $$F(k) = \frac1{ k^2 + a^2 },~ a>0$$

Here is what I have so far: 
 
Singular points at $k^2 = a^2$, namely, at $k = \pm ia$. The inverse transform by definition is
$$\;f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}F(k)e^{ikx}dk~.$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \frac1{2\pi}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{e^{ikx}}{k^2+a^2}dk \\ 
&= \frac1{2\pi} \left[ \int^{0}_{-\infty}\frac{e^{ikx}}{k^2+a^2}dk + \int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{e^{ikx}}{k^2+a^2}dk \right] \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}2\pi i \cdot \sum(\operatorname{Res})
\end{align}
Where do I go from here?

Comment: What do you denote *Res* ?

Comment: The residue of the function

Comment: And the sum is taken w.r.t. which index?

Comment: It's arbitrary. It just means to take the sum of all of the residues with respect to the singular points that are inside the contour. So normally the next step would be the set that last equation equal to (e^ikx/2k; k = ia)+(e^ikx/2k; k = -ia) (which are the residues), but I don't know if I need both of them, or if one of them will go to 0. We worked with inverse Laplace where if x<0, then it vanishes. But we didn't talk about inverse Fourier

Comment: To check your answer when you get it: See page 3 ... http://uspas.fnal.gov/materials/11ODU/FourierTransformPairs.pdf

Comment: In order to use contour integration, you will need to write down the contour you will use.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that $x$ is real. You need to pick either the upper or the lower semicircle, based on the sign of $x$. Let $k=u+iv$ (i.e. $\Re(k)=:u$, $\Im(k)=:v$), then we have that
$$e^{ikx}=e^{i(u+iv)x}=e^{iux}e^{-vx}$$
We want $e^{ikx} \to 0$. The first part just oscillates, so we don't need to care about it. The second part goes to $0$ if $vx \to \infty$, i.e. we need $vx$ to be positive. So which semicircle do we need if $x>0$, and which one if $x<0$?

Comment: For x < 0, we need the upper-half plane and for x > 0 we would need the lower-half plane, right?

Comment: @AmandaLococo What's the sign of the imaginary part of the numbers on the lower half plane?

Comment: The pole in the upper-half plane are k = ia, and the pole in the lower half is k = -ia. I can calculate the residues and get -sin(ax)/a, but apparently this solution is incorrect

Comment: @AmandaLococo I think you are summing both residues. But you will only have $1$ inside the contour in both cases, and the sign of $x$ will decide which one.

Comment: Should I only have the the case for k = ia to get e^iak/2a?

Comment: @AmandaLococo You are almost right. How do you calculate the residue of $\frac{e^{ikx}}{k^2+a^2}$ at $k=ia$?

Comment: Just take the derivative of the denominator wrt k and the plug in k = ia. So, we have e^i*iax/2ia = e^-ax/2ia

Comment: @AmandaLococo It looks better now! And which half plane do we need to choose when $x>0$ and which one when $x<0$?

Comment: Choose the upper half plane for x < 0 and the lower half place for x > 0.

Comment: @AmandaLococo Why?

Comment: Wait. Will that cause the function to blow up? I'm not actually sure why here.

Comment: @AmandaLococo Do you understand my work with $k=u+iv$?

Comment: I understand what you did, but I'm not sure why you did it.

Comment: @AmandaLococo If you want to calculate an integral with the residue theorem, you need to close the contour. If you do it with a half-circle, then you will have that $2 i \pi \sum \text{Res} = \int_{A} + \int_{B}$, where $\int_{A}$ is the integral you want to calculate and $\int_{B}$ is the integral on the half-circle. We want $\int_{B}$ to be $0$ to have that $2 i \pi \sum \text{Res}$ is the original integral. We need to examinate the $\int_{B}$ wether it goes to $0$ or not, but in the application when you have an exponential function in the nominator and polynomial in the denominator...

Comment: @AmandaLococo ... the exponential function will make sure that the integral indeed vanishes if the exponential function goes to $0$ on the contour. So I checked how can we make it to go to $0$.